# I am trying to convert xml to json using groovy script .how can i get in iteratively so that i dont need to give index manually

Tags: json, xml, groovy

here is the xml

```
  <book>
    <title>Groovy</title>
    <author>Ken Barclay</author>
    <publisher>Elsevier</publisher>
    <isbn number='1111111111' />
  </book>
  <book>
    <title>Object Oriented Design</title>
    <author>John Savage</author>
    <publisher>Elsevier</publisher>
    <isbn number='2222222222' />
  </book>
  <book>
    <title>C Programming</title>
    <author>Ken Barclay</author>
    <publisher>Prentice Hall</publisher>
    <isbn number='3333333333' />
  </book>
</catalogoue>
```

and here is the script that i wrote

```
import groovy.util.*
import java.io.*
import groovy.xml.*
import groovy.json.JsonBuilder
def trial = new XmlParser()
def test = trial. Parse("C:/Users/lenovo/Desktop/1b adangals/groovy/library.xml");
def nam ="${test.book[0].title.text()}"
println "${it.test.book[0].publisher. Text()}"
def writer = new StringWriter()
def builder = new JsonBuilder(writer)
builder.doc {
    dox {
    /*doc "${(test.book[0].text())}"*/
    name "${nam}"
    }
    scripter "${test.book[0].publisher. Text()}"

}
println builder.toPrettyString()
println "${nam}"
```

i have to develop a customized json from above xml ,where I am getting data from the first part only due to given index [0] .how can get it in iterative way?

the solution I needed is without ',' separator in JSON and "doc" as Root node .

````
      "doc": { 
          "dox": { "name": "Groovy" 
                 } 
          "dox": { "name": "Object Oriented Design"
                 } 
          "dox": { "name": "C Programming"
                 } 
          } ```
 like this .
"scripter" is not required.
Could you help me out here.It would be helpful to me if you suggest me any references to work on JSON-XML & vice versa conversions using groovy.
````

Answer (score 0):

```js
import groovy.xml.*
import groovy.json.JsonBuilder

def trial = new XmlParser()
def test = trial.parseText('''
<catalogoue>
  <book>
    <title>Groovy</title>
    <author>Ken Barclay</author>
    <publisher>Elsevier</publisher>
    <isbn number='1111111111' />
  </book>
  <book>
    <title>Object Oriented Design</title>
    <author>John Savage</author>
    <publisher>Elsevier</publisher>
    <isbn number='2222222222' />
  </book>
  <book>
    <title>C Programming</title>
    <author>Ken Barclay</author>
    <publisher>Prentice Hall</publisher>
    <isbn number='3333333333' />
  </book>
</catalogoue>
''')

def data = 
    [
        doc: test.book.collect{book->
            [
                dox:[
                    name: book.title.text()
                ],
                //scripter: book.publisher.text()
            ]
        }
    ]


def builder = new JsonBuilder(data)
println builder.toPrettyString()
```

result:

```
{
    "doc": [
        {
            "dox": {
                "name": "Groovy"
            }
        },
        {
            "dox": {
                "name": "Object Oriented Design"
            }
        },
        {
            "dox": {
                "name": "C Programming"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: hi @dagett ,thanks for the help but the solution I got is as follows```[
    {
        "doc": {
            "dox": {
                "name": "Groovy"
            },
            "scripter": "Elsevier"
        }
    },
    {
        "doc": {
            "dox": {
                "name": "Object Oriented Design"
            },
            "scripter": "Elsevier"
        }
    },
    {
        "doc": {
            "dox": {
                "name": "C Programming"
            },
            "scripter": "Prentice Hall"
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: could you put the expected result in question. comments definitely not for this...

Comment: edited the question with expected result

Comment: changed the answer a bit

Comment: thanks @daggett. I also tried ```d2=[doc:"${data}"]``` in the script and I am getting ```{
    "doc": "[[dox:[name: Groovy]], [dox:[name: Object Oriented Design]], [dox:[name: C Programming]]]"
} ```. the map is not getting converted to JSON completely. can you tell me why its failing?

Comment: My answer produces Json. `[doc:"${data}"]` is incorrect because you are converting value to string...